# Passing a variable to include in extends in Django templates

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have the following structure of templates:

`main.html`

```
<html>
<body>
  <p>
    This works: {% block title %}{% endblock %}
  </p>

  {% include 'heading.html' with title=title %} {# but this does not work since it is not a variable #}
</body>
</html>
```

`heading.html`

```
<p>
  {{ title }}
</p>
```

`page.html`

```
{% extends 'main.html' %}

{% block title %}test title{% endblock %}
```

How can I pass the title from `page.html` to `heading.html`? Ideally, it should be defined as a block like now, but alternatives are also welcome. I'd like to contain the solution within the templates if possible.

Clarification:

This is a minimal example, but I have multiple pages like `main.html` that share a larger header that has title and some other variables that I'd like defined in the child template (not necessarily as variable as long as the text is passed).

I could put the title into the view code, but this solution would just decrease the separation of displayed data from the logic.

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate because I wanted to put the value in an included template which limits the usage of `block`, but it seems the same approach as over there may work.

Comment: That is what was asked in the other question as well...

Comment: I don't see any mention of `{% include %}` in the question of the one you linked. They just want to pass information to the parent, which can be done via `block`. I want to pass it to something included in the parent template. Either way, I am fine with marking this question as duplicate after I finish the bounty. Is there anything in SO that prevents marking this question as duplicate due to the bounty after it is finished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `block` around the `include` with variables, and then wrap `{{ block.super }}` in the [`with`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/builtins/#with) template tag.

main.html:

```html
<html>
<body>
  <p>
    This works: {% block title %}{% endblock %}
  </p>

  {% block with_variables %}
    {% include 'heading.html' %}
  {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

page.html:

```html
{% extends 'main.html' %}

{% block title %}test title{% endblock %}

{% block with_variables %}
    {% with title="variable title" %}
        {{ block.super }}
    {% endwith %}
{% endblock %}
```

You may name it `{% block heading %}`, or nest the whole main.html in `{% block content %}`.

Answer (score 1):

instead of {% include %}, you might want to use [custom template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/custom-template-tags/) tags with returning **html** or extension like [slippers](https://mitchel.me/slippers/)

Comment: How would custom template tags enable passing data to template included in extended template? Even if I saved the value somewhere, what guarantee do I have that the custom tag in `page.html` is executed before reading the title in `heading.html`?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `heading.html`. You can use the context variable `title` directly; as long as you pass it to your `render` function in your view, e.g.:

`views.py`

```py
def my_view(request):
    context = {'title': 'Hello World!'}
    return render(request, 'page.html', context=context)
```

`main.html`

```html
<html>
<body>
  <p>
    This is my title:
    {% block title %}{% endblock %}
  </p>
</body>
</html>
```

`page.html`

```html
{% extends 'main.html' %}

{% block title %}
  <strong>{{title}}</strong>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: This is a minimal example but I need it due to it (and some more variables) being shared by multiple extended main templates.

Comment: @Xilexio: In my answer I mentioned that the variable title is visible in an included heading,html if you add title to the context. It is not clear what "shared by multiple extended main templates" means as the include is in the main.html in your original question. Maybe you can define more clear where title should be declared as a variable and where it should be transfered to.

Comment: The title should be declared in the child template. By multiple mains I mean that I have a few top-level templates which share the header. To reduce code duplication, I put it into include. Each of these mains has its own children like in the example.

Comment: @Xilexio This example shows exectly how to declare the title in a child template (page.html), so that it is displayed in the main template (main.html). What do you mean by "multiple extended main templates"? Templates are rendered in a tree-like, with the main one being the "root" of the tree, and the child templates the leafs (or branches if you, in turn, extend the child templates). Are you sure that you understand the difference between context variables (`{{ title }}`) and template blocks (`{% block title %}`)? Are you perhaps looking for a way to specify global context variables?

Comment: The point of the question is that I need the title not in `main.html` but in `heading.html`, which is included in `main.html`. And blocks do not work in included templates. Therefore, while it is a valid approach in most cases, it is not in mine. By "multiple main templates" I was trying to convey that I have at least two pages like `main.html` that both include the same `heading.html` and that have child pages like `page.html`. This is why include is needed to remove the duplication and I cannot simply inline `heading.html` in `main.html` without duplicating its content.

Answer (score 1):

If you have administrative rights to your Django installation, an easy and elegant solution would be to switch your Django's template renderer to [Jinja2](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/) instead using [django-jinja](https://niwi.nz/django-jinja/latest/) as a backend.

The main advantage of Jinja2 for the needs of this question is that it supports assignment of a block to a variable through [block assignments](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#block-assignments). Since Jinja2 is inspired by the Django template language, your existing templates will need few modifications, if any.

With Jinja2 as a template renderer, you can set the `title` variable with a block of HTML content in the child template:

**page.html**

```
{% extends 'main.html' %}

{% set title %}test title{% endset %}
```

The `title` variable will then work in the shared template:

**main.html**

```
<html>
<body>
  <p>
    Main template works: {{ title }}
  </p>
{% include 'heading.html' %}
</body>
</html>
```

And it will also work in the included template:

**heading.html**

```
  <p>
    Included template also works: {{ title }}
  </p>
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/AlarmedCleverDebugmonitor

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It is also very good, but I chose aaron's because yours requires usage of an additional (popular) package, making it a bit more costly for an existing project. And I had to choose one.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to split `heading.html` into two and add a `{% block %}` in-between, but this is an ugly workaround that is prone to bugs with unclosed tags.

I am searching for a better alternative.

`main.html`

```
...
{% include 'heading1.html' %} {# containing <p> #}
{% block title %}{% endblock %}
{% include 'heading2.html' %} {# containing </p> #}
...
```

Additionally, if white spaces are important, there has to be no new line between includes and the block.

Answer (score 0):

add your title to the rendering context and it will be visible in page, main and included heading.